# Swift UITableView auto height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

I have a design, where UITableView is in UIScrollView with other content and the content is scrolling with the table data. It means, that table has scrolling disabled and is stretched to full size.

I'm using autolayout and the table has height constraint, set to some default value.

Then I have overwritten viewWillLayoutSubviews method:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    if (self.itemTableView.contentSize.height > 0) {
        self.itemTableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.itemTableView.contentSize.height
    }
}
```

With this method in place, when I called self.itemTableView.reloadData() after loading the data from the REST, the height constraint was set to table content height, which was great.

This used to work for me in many projects, but for some reason it is not working in the latest one, written in swift 4. Does something changed? Why tableView reloadData() method does not invoke viewWillLayoutSubviews()?

Comment: You should never embed a `UITableView` inside a `UIScrollView`. You could use the header or footer view from the table, or add custom cells in different sections for your other scrollable data around the content cells of your tableview

Comment: It should work fine. check for any other possible issue

Comment: @TmKVU thank you, that make sense. I will consider this approach.

Comment: @Satish I thought it should work, because I'm using this in my older projects and it is working. But for some reason, it is not working in this one. So I was wondering if something was changed in Swift recently.

Comment: iOS11+ has added "contentLayoutGuide" and "frameLayoutGuide" constraints which change the way you constrain subviews to a scrollView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) was not calling self.view.setNeedsLayout() before returning row.